# Prism 8 Handling Resolution Errors

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Basically what I do is I want to handling resolution errors based on here https://prismlibrary.com/docs/dependency-injection/resolution-errors.html but I am not sure how to do it because we actually don't use `ModuleManager` but from what I understanding is prism use it internally. Maybe anyone know how to do it or any samples that we can look at? By the way we are using xamarin.forms and prism 8. We are preparing to upgrade to MAUI so that's why we upgrade the prism to 8